# To watch the play without knowing the story

Tags: word-choice

I would like to know if there is an idiom or a proverb in English to denote a situation in which one watches a play or a dramatic performance without knowing its story.
It is similar to participating in a discussion and opining in it without having much idea about the incident on which the discussion is in progress.

I would use the expression in a context like: "I don't know really what happened earlier, who said it, to whom and what exactly. So, my interference is (like)......"

Comment: Do you mean without knowing what happened earlier – not starting at the beginning?

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, I don't have the details of the incident, still I opine on it.

Comment: I see, in BrE there is a rude expression for that: ["talking out of one's arse"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/talk_out_of_one's_arse).

Comment: In AmE, it is of course [“talking out of one’s ass”](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/talking+out+of+your+ass).

Comment: @StevenBurnap Both the idioms (Yours and Weather Vane's) are vulgar slangs as per the dictionary of idioms, and they mean a foolish talk. My idea is that the interference that I mentioned is not necessarily a foolish attempt, but rather irrelevant.

Comment: They do not mean"foolish" so much as "ignorant".

Comment: Are you talking about arriving at the play midway through? Or are you talking about not paying any attention to what happens during the play? Or perhaps you mean not knowing the plot before it starts—but still talking about it anyway (before it starts)?

Comment: @mahmudkoya I don't understand the scenario you are talking about, so it's hard to come up with an idiom to address it.  When you watch a play, you don't know the story (unless you've seen the play before). Also, you don't normally participate in the play you are watching, so I don't see how that connects to participating in a conversation.  Do you mean "understand" instead of "know"? As in someone watched the play but didn't understand it?

Answer (score 1):

**go in cold**

One definition of "go in cold" is "to begin or do something without planning, preparation, or practice."

Example:
I try to avoid watching any previews or ads for movies, because I prefer to go in cold.

Answer (score 0):

**to have no idea what one is talking about**

Example:

> Well, I have no idea what I'm talking about, but I can tell you my opinion about this, for what it's worth.  Etc.

Alternative:

> Well, this might be completely off base, but my uneducated opinion is etc.

This expression comes from baseball.